# Accidentally used ETH address to receive token from polkadot

Tags: polkadot, balances, cryptography

I accidentally used my ETH address to receive token from Polkadot.
Is there any way I can access my tokens with my private key? Thanks.

For example: https://polkaholic.io/account/49zaADFp2kjgEJhmUWp1aq4zVc6fGBnSNFEUa4b2WAvxF73X?group=overview&chainfilters=all

Eth address: `0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1`

Public key in Polkaholic: `0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Not directly, you have to utilize governance (success not guaranteed).

Ethereum uses the [Elliptic Curve secp256k1](https://ethereum.org/sr/developers/docs/evm/) to derive a public key from a private key, whereas Polkadot uses the [Edward Curve sr25519](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/cryptography/). This means that the public keys, that are derived from the same private key in Ethereum and Polkadot, differ. Consequently, you cannot access your funds directly if you sent tokens to the same public key but in another network.

The only solution to that problem I see is to [utilize governance](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-democracy) . You will have to ask all token holders to unlock your funds. For that you have to lock DOT until your proposal is tabled as a referendum and finally decided by all token holders in the network. To have a chance at all that token holders accept your referendum, you have to explain the situation in all detail and provide a signature made with your Ethereum account over the message that explains the issue (don't forget to include a timestamp).

Note that Polkadot still uses Gov 1.0 instead of Gov 2.0 (OpenGov), which means that you'll have a lot of competing proposals that receive backing to be tabled faster as a referendum, as there can be only one proposal tabled at a time in Polkadot (with the exception of fast-tracked proposals).

Good Luck.